# Why is this mosquitto broker inaccessible to remote machines? "Error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Tags: windows, linux-networking

My mosquitto broker is currently binded to address 192.168.2.1 on port 1883. Publishing and subscribing both work fine for programs running on the host machine where mosquitto is running (call this the Linux machine) But all remote machines cannot access the broker with pubs or subs (denote remote machines Wind10).

## Client machines Wind10

They produce the following errors when attempting to publish either ---.1 or ---.104,

```
> .\mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.2.1 -p 1883 -t newsTest -m "remotePayload427" -u redacted -P redacted
    Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

    > .\mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.2.104 -p 1883 -t newsTest -m "remotePayload427" -u redacted -P redacted
    Error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

    > ipconfig

    Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
       Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::64e1:2bdf:413b:7660%16
       IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.104
       Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
       Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
```

Ports forwarded in firewall .

[image: Windows Firewall outbound settings]

[image: Windows Firewall inbound settings]

## Host. Linux machine

The Linux machine is running the broker. Here is its current configuration.

```
]# more /etc/mosquitto/mosqClean.conf
user mosquit
bind_address 192.168.2.1
port 1883
protocol mqtt
log_dest syslog
log_type all
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/plaintext


]# tail -f /var/log/mosquitto.log
2022-09-15T21:21:53.389752-04:00 mtcap mosquitto[23132]: mosquitto version 1.6.14 starting
2022-09-15T21:21:53.392443-04:00 mtcap mosquitto[23132]: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosqClean.conf.
2022-09-15T21:21:53.395912-04:00 mtcap mosquitto[23132]: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
2022-09-15T21:21:53.406287-04:00 mtcap mosquitto[23132]: mosquitto version 1.6.14 running


]# netstat -t
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.1:ssh         192.168.2.104:56381     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.1:ssh         192.168.2.104:50539     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.1:ssh         192.168.2.104:50541     ESTABLISHED

]# netstat -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:http            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:domain          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.1:1883        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:https           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::domain               :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::ssh                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::https                :::*                    LISTEN
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:domain          0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:bootps          0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 :::domain               :::*

]# more /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

]# ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:08:00:4B:DB:96
          inet addr:192.168.2.1  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:305983 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:331765 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:24324031 (23.1 MiB)  TX bytes:42568583 (40.5 MiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:08:00:4B:DB:96
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:306569 errors:0 dropped:577 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:335070 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:24432998 (23.3 MiB)  TX bytes:42747053 (40.7 MiB)
          Interrupt:22 Base address:0xc000
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:165515 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:165515 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:19274042 (18.3 MiB)  TX bytes:19274042 (18.3 MiB)
```

Notice that in `netstat -t` there are active ssh sessions on ----.1 . Are these interfering with the broker?

Comment: I'm not really clear what's going on here: you can't just assign random bind addresses to your mosquitto configuration and hope it will work; you can only assign ip addresses that exist on the host.  From your `ifconfig` output, the only address assigned on your Linux is host `192.168.2.1`, so you wouldn't expect anything else to work. You also wouldn't typically use `192.168.2.255`, because that's the network broadcast address.

Comment: @larsks  ,  The Wind10 clients are leasing over 192.168.2.100 to .254    In your opinion, should I assign another address below 100 in /etc/network/interfaces and then bind the broker to it?

Comment: If your broker is running on your linux system at `192.168.2.1`, then you should just use that address as the bind address in your server configuration (and as the server address in your client configuration). If your broker is running somewhere else, please update your question to make that more explicit.

Comment: @larsks  I have used 192.168.2.1  as the bind address.  The clients still produce the following errors ,  > .\mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.2.1 -p 1883 -t newsTest -m "remotePayload427" -u redacted -P redacted
    Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

    > .\mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.2.104 -p 1883 -t newsTest -m "remotePayload427" -u redacted -P redacted
    Error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.